# pageX, pageY to chartX, chartY's datapoints not coord highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to convert the coordinates of the entire page's X and Y coordinates to the chart's point?

I know you can get it in reverse.

```
var manualPt = {pageX:155, pageY: 242} //<--the point I want to display
//on the chart as a datapoint and not a chartX, chartY coordinate.

function onClick(e) {
    $('#report').text('x: ' + e.pageX+ ', y: ' + e.pageY).css({
        'position': 'absolute',
            'left': e.offsetX,
            'top': e.offsetY
    })
   //this would be the reverse.. knowing where the point on the chart is 
   //and then get pageX and pageY
}

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {},
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        events: {
            click: onClick
        }

    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pinktoadette/yd6vrg4o/

How can I accomplish this? Also it is possible that the coords of pageX and pageY may not be a data series in the existing chart.

Comment: The entire page (also outside the chart?) or just the chart div, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-click/?

Comment: outside of the chart. So the provided pageX and pageY is retrieved from a parent. I'm trying to pass this parent coord to child, within child is highcharts.

Comment: How do you imagine such a point is plotted? Since it is outside of the bounds of highcharts, what should that point look like? I think that you would need to create your own function that translates the `pageX` and `pageY` into coordinates, based on the windowsize.

Comment: it'll be a point, assuming it's within the highcharts element. how do i transfer the pageX to the chart's data, that is my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the pixel position of the point relative to the chart and use axis `toValue` method to get real data:

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    events: {
        load() {
            var chart = this,
                xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
                yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
                container = chart.renderTo,
                x = xAxis.toValue(manualPt.pageX - container.offsetLeft),
                y = yAxis.toValue(manualPt.pageY - container.offsetTop);

            this.series[1].addPoint({
                x: x,
                y: y
            });
        }
    }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toValue

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5pytc8mb/